# SQL Server Custom Identity Column

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, identity

I want to generate a custom identity column related to type of product.
Can this query guaranty the order of identity and resolve concurrency.
This is a sample query:

```
BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO TBLKEY
VALUES((SELECT 'A-' + CAST(MAX(CAST(ID AS INT)) + 1 AS NVARCHAR) FROM TBLKEY),'EHSAN')

COMMIT
```

Comment: instead of +1 try to use sequence.

Comment: @DudiKonfino,  i can't use identity or sequence and a computed field because the continuous of number is related to product type, like this 10001 productA, 20001 productB

Comment: You can create with start at 10001 and step 10000

Comment: It seems that you believe that your set needs to be contiguous. This is a common mis-belief. That is, what business reason do you have for this other than the ID space will look pretty? Use the tools that SQL Server gives you (namely an identity column or a sequence value) and make your life a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO TBLKEY
VALUES((SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 AS NVARCHAR) FROM TBLKEY WITH (UPDLOCK)),'EHSAN')

COMMIT
```

When selecting the max ID you acquire a U lock on the row. The U lock is incompatible with the U lock which will try to acquire another session with the same query running at the same time. Only one query will be executed at a given time. The ids will be in order and continuous without any gaps between them.

A better solution would be to create an extra table dedicated only for storing the current or next id and use it instead of the maximum.

You can understand the difference by doing the following:

Prepare a table

```
CREATE TABLE T(id int not null PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED)
INSERT INTO T VALUES(1)
```

And then run the following query in two different sessions one after another with less than 10 seconds apart

```
BEGIN TRAN
DECLARE @idv int
SELECT @idv = max (id) FROM T
WAITFOR DELAY '0:0:10'
INSERT INTO T VALUES(@idv+1)
COMMIT
```

Wait for a while until both queries complete. Observe that one of them succeeded and the other failed.

Now do the same with the following query

```
BEGIN TRAN
DECLARE @idv int
SELECT @idv = max (id) FROM T WITH (UPDLOCK)
WAITFOR DELAY '0:0:5'
INSERT INTO T VALUES(@idv+1)
COMMIT
```

View the contents of T

Cleanup the T Table with `DROP TABLE T`

Comment: thanks, i tested only Select statement as you say in two different transactions and worked fine.

Comment: It would probably work and without the UPDLOCK but it would not be right.

Comment: with UPDLOCK also i can put new id into a variable and use that in Insert statement: `BEGIN TRAN
DECLARE @NEWID AS NVARCHAR  SET @NEWID = (SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 AS NVARCHAR) FROM TBLKEY WITH (UPDLOCK))
INSERT INTO TBLKEY
VALUES(@NEWID,'EHSAN')

COMMIT` is it right?

Answer (score 0):

This would be a bad thing to do as there is no way to guarantee that two queries running at the same time wouldn't get MAX(ID) as being the same value.

If you used a standard identity column you could also have a computed column which uses that or just return the key when you return the data.

Ed

Comment: He could make his attempt work if he changed the query to FROM TBLKEY WITH (UPDLOCK). This way two queries running at the same time could not get the same MAX(ID) one of them would be blocked by the other. Additionally, I think that the produced ids would not only be in ascending order but they would be continuous too. The drawback of this way is that all parallel queries are serialized.

Comment: Not to mention that CAST(ID AS INT) is of the form CAST('A-XXXX') which would fail.

Comment: @Ed Elliot, i can't use identity and a computed field because the continuous of number is related to product type, like this 10001 productA, 20001 productB.

Comment: @Blim, I know above CAST has error but i said it's only a sample.

Comment: @Ehsan I understood it but i thought to mention it for future reference. Try the UPDLOCK hint you can find more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx)