# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Generating unique number

Tags: sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2008-r2, locking

### Requirement

I want a way to generate a new unique number (Invoice Number) in a continuous sequence (no number should be left out when generating a new number)

**Valid Example**: 1, 2, 3, 4

**Invalid Example**: 1, 2, 4, 3 (not in a continuous sequence)

### Current Schema

Here is my existing table schema of the table **Test**
[image]

### Solution i came up with

After doing some research i came up with the below code which seems to be working as of now.

```
DECLARE @i as int=0
While(@i<=10000 * 10000)
BEGIN
    Begin Transaction

        Insert Into Test(UniqueNo,[Text])values((Select     IsNull(MAX(UniqueNo),0)+1 from Test with (TABLOCK)),'a')
    COMMIT  

    SET @i = @i + 1;
END
```

### Testing

I tried running the code from 12 different SQL Query or 12 threads you can say and currently it generates new and unique value for each records even after inserting **162,921 rows**
[image]

### Main Question

Can the above code result into duplicate values?

I tried it by hit-and-trial method and it works perfectly **BUT** when i go in-depth of ***Transaction Locking*** the select statement generates a **Shared Lock** for the whole table that means it will allow concurrent transactions to access the same data, right?

That means that multiple transactions can generate duplicate values, right?

Then how come i am not able to see any duplicate values yet?

### EDIT

**As per david's comment** 
I cannot use identity field because in any case if i delete a record then it would be difficult for me to fill that number up.

Comment: Why not just use an [IDENTITY column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017) and let SQL Server create the values for you?

Comment: @DavidG because if anyone delete's any row then i wont be able to use that number ever again

Comment: Well that's not clear from your question, and your code above does not do that either. Another question then: why do you care about having these continuous values?

Comment: @DavidG, actually these continuous numbers are Invoice number which have to be in a sequence .

Comment: Why do you care if invoice numbers are sequential though? Also, you probably shouldn't be exposing sequential numbers to clients like this.

Comment: @SalmanA but the continuous series means the same, doesn't it?

Comment: The main question is will the TABLOCK ever fail?

Comment: So you are concerned that deleting invoice 2 will cause problems? Why would that be a problem? What if you delete invoice 2 and then insert a new one tomorrow? The dates will be all out of order. I think you fundamentally misunderstand what the law is there, there's no way that can work.

Comment: @DavidG i might be wrong and i am sorry if i am being rude BUT the main thing for me to focus on is is that TABLOCK ever going to fail?

Comment: I'm just pointing out that you are almost certainly wasting your time doing this. I don't know if the tablock is going to work, but it looks like a terribly hacky method, and relying on it in production is not something I would accept in my code. But if that's the road you want to go down, then I wish you luck.

Comment: Agree with David. And if this column must be unique, then it should have a unique constraint. And let's take this a step further. What purpose does Id serve? And we see UniqueNo and Text (what a terrible name) are both nullable. TBH you just aren't trying to define proper DDL (even if this is a disposable for-verification purposes).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Custom Identity Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937401/sql-server-custom-identity-column)

Comment: Anytime you try to roll your own identity like functionality it will fail. There are just way too many scenarios for things to go wrong. However, some countries (like Mexico) require you to submit invoices to the government and they MUST be sequentially numbered. The way I have dealt with this is to use an identity for the table. Then have a second column SubmittedInvoiceID to hold the sequential values. I use a sequence to generate those numbers at the time they are submitted.

Comment: @SeanLange How does that work with OPs problem of deleting invoices? That clearly breaks the sequential nature and it's not like you can go through and renumber them all?

Comment: @DavidG maybe the question should be why in the world are invoices being deleted in the first place? I offered it only as an example of a way perfectly sequential numbering was handled for a project I worked on.

Comment: @SeanLange Indeed. The requirements to have contiguous values and also be able to delete are mutually exclusive, no amount of TABLOCKs are going to help.

Answer (score -1):

this is the procedure can create your countinues check number

```
create procedure [dbo].[aa] @var int
as
declare @isexists int=0
declare @lastnum int=0
set @isexists=(select isnull((select [text] from t000test where [text]=@var),0))
if(isnull(@isexists,0)<=0)
begin 
 set @lastnum=(select isnull( max([text]),0) from t000test )
 if(@var>@lastnum)
 begin
  insert into t000test(text) values (@var)
 end
 else
  print 'your number dose not in rang'
end
else
print 'your number exists in the data'
GO
```

you can test this procedure like this :

`exec dbo.aa 6` --or any number u like

and this loop create your number automaticly by range u like to

```
declare @yourrange int =50
declare @id int =0;
while @yourrange>0
begin
exec dbo.aa @id
set @id=@id+1;
set @yourrange=@yourrange-1;
end
```

I am using 50 but you can use more range or less

Comment: thanks for the reply but it is not helpful at all because my code is at least protecting it from data duplicacy by transaction locking and as far as i can make out of your code you are just trying to validate data from DB without transaction locking which will generate a duplicate number in short-term if more than 12 threads are trying to insert the data simultaneously